# Is there a list of computed Wigner distributions of notable states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, quantum-optics, wigner-transform

I'm looking for a list of explicit expressions of [Wigner distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasiprobability_distribution) of notable functions (*e.g.*, Fock states, Gaussian states, thermal states, etc).

Is there a paper, book, or other online source featuring something like this?

Comment: You are unhappy with the explicit answers scattered in the standard books by [Schleich](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/3527602976), [Curtright, Fairlie, and Zachos](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf), and [Leon Cohen](https://www.amazon.com/Time-Frequency-Analysis-Theory-Applications/dp/0135945321/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&qid=1599158616&refinements=p_27%3ALeon+Cohen&s=books&sr=1-3&text=Leon+Cohen)?

Comment: @CosmasZachos thanks for the links, that's useful. Well, it's not the I'm unhappy with it, but I was hoping there was a compiled list somewhere, which would be useful to use as reference. I guess Wikipedia would be a good place for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a Mathematica script which computes Wigner functions for differernt quantum harmonic oscillator pure states and plots them. Here is the link:
https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/WignerFunctionOfHarmonicOscillator/

Comment: looking at the code generating the figures, they are just using the explicit formula $(-1)^n e^{-p^2-q^2}L_n(2(p^2+q^2))/\pi$ with $L_n$ the $n$-th Laguerre function